# How to remove or ignore the false 404 errors in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-status-code-404

I built a website, everything is running fine. It's just behind the scenes where there's a problem. When I go to access the page I get several errors in the console for some images file that are loaded dynamically, all looking similar to this

```
GET http://website.com/imgs/%7B%7Bpage.symbolF%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

this is what I have in the html

```
<img src="imgs/{{page.symbol}}" width="200" height="200" />
```

But like I said, everything works and the images load fine, so it seems angular isn't loading right away for some reason and not processing the interpolations. Is there a way to fix this or "mute" the 404s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) to solve this problem:

```
<img ng-src="imgs/{{page.symbol}}" width="200" height="200" />
```